# Function that returns a string from an array of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, pointers

I need to declare a function that returns a string from an array of pointers .. I am programming a PIC and I am using as an interface an LCD ..
With this code I have what I want:

```
// CONFIGURATION BITS
#pragma config FOSC = HS   // Oscillator Selection bits (XT oscillator)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF  // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF // Brown-out Reset Enable bit (BOR disabled)
#pragma config LVP = OFF   // Low-Voltage In-Circuit Serial Programming Enable bit
#pragma config CPD = OFF   // Data EEPROM Memory Code Protection bit 
#pragma config WRT = OFF   // Flash Program Memory Write Enable bits 
#pragma config CP = OFF    // Flash Program Memory Code Protection bit

#define _XTAL_FREQ 8000000

// DEFINING LCD PINS
#define RS RD2
#define EN RD3
#define D4 RD4
#define D5 RD5
#define D6 RD6
#define D7 RD7

#include <xc.h>

#include "lcd.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{

    TRISD = 0x00;           //PORTD as output for LCD
    Lcd_Init();
    Lcd_Clear();

    while(1)
    {

        Lcd_Set_Cursor(1,1);

        char *keypress;
        int key = 2;
        char *key2[] = {"3", "4", "5"}; 
        keypress = key2[key];

        Lcd_Write_String(keypress);

        __delay_ms(50);

    }
}
```

[image]

I obtain "5" .. That is what I want .. But when I try to make a function for that..

```
// CONFIGURATION BITS
#pragma config FOSC = HS   // Oscillator Selection bits (XT oscillator)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF  // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF // Brown-out Reset Enable bit (BOR disabled)
#pragma config LVP = OFF   // Low-Voltage In-Circuit Serial Programming Enable bit
#pragma config CPD = OFF   // Data EEPROM Memory Code Protection bit 
#pragma config WRT = OFF   // Flash Program Memory Write Enable bits 
#pragma config CP = OFF    // Flash Program Memory Code Protection bit

#define _XTAL_FREQ 8000000

// DEFINING LCD PINS
#define RS RD2
#define EN RD3
#define D4 RD4
#define D5 RD5
#define D6 RD6
#define D7 RD7

#include <xc.h>

#include "lcd.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char kbd_getc();

char kbd_getc(){

    int key = 2;
    char *key2[] = {"3", "4", "5"}; 
    return key2[key];

}

void main()
{

    TRISD = 0x00;           //PORTD as output for LCD
    Lcd_Init();
    Lcd_Clear();

    while(1)
    {

        Lcd_Set_Cursor(1,1);

        char *keypress;

        keypress = kbd_getc();

        Lcd_Write_String(keypress);

        __delay_ms(50);

    }
}
```

[image]

I don't understand why do I get mm .. I am not sure if I am declaring the function incorrectly or I am doing something wrong with the pointers, thanks

Comment: The root of the problem here is that the infamous PIC compiler "MPLAB", or whatever that crap is called nowadays, is bad. A working C compiler would have pointed out the language violation at `return key2[key];`, which comes from accidentally using `char kbd_getc()` rather than as intended: `char* kbd_getc()`.

Comment: As a side note, pointers to string literals should be declared as `const char*`. They will be stored in flash.

Comment: As another side note, `void main()` is not standard-compliant. `main()` should return an `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    char *key2[] = {"3", "4", "5"}; 
    return key2[key];
```

Here, `key2` is an array of `char` pointers and `key2[key]` is pointer at index `key` of array `key2` which is pointing to first character of a string.
Now, look at the return type of function `kbd_getc()`:

```
char kbd_getc(){
^^^^
```

Its a `char` type. That means, you are returning a string from function which is suppose to return a character.
If I write a simple program to check your `kbd_getc()`, I am getting following warning message on statement `return key2[key];` -

```
warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion returning 'char *' from a function with result type 'char';
```

If I change the return type to `char *`

```
char * kbd_getc(){
```

the warning message disappear and I get the desired output:

```
$ ./a.out 
5
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function returns `char` but you return a `char *`.

Change the return type to `char *`

And up your compiler warning to catch those things.

Comment: I don't know enough about the specifics of your application, I just told you what is wrong with your C.  You (I expect) need to change the return to `char *`. Which did you do?

Comment: I change: char kbd_getc(){  to: char * kbd_getc(){   Now it works, thanks

Comment: There is no need to "up" compiler warnings, the code contains a constraint violation and a conforming compiler must give a diagnostic message. So the solution is rather to change to a standard C compiler.

Answer (score -2):

Just try this,

```
char kbd_getc(){

int key = 2;
char *key2[] = {"3", "4", "5"}; 
char a = key2[key];
return a ;

}
```

I think That u r returning array.

You need to return a char.

Thank you

Comment: Same problem, same bug. Your code returns a `char *` from a `char` function. I think the function should return `char *`

Comment: Ya , i think that key pressed is char.. plz change that to char* , if then change the method name to char *